# Better fitting of error function on the data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am fitting an error function with several parameters, `a,b,mu,sigma` to the data. But for some reason, the fit is not that good around the hump as highlighted below. How can I have a better fit with the error function? I am also open to modifying the `func(x, a, b, mu, sigma)` if that would serve the purpose of a better fit especially round the hump.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy

def func(x, a, b, mu, sigma):
    y = a * scipy.special.erf((x-mu) / (sigma * np.sqrt(2))) + b
    return y

def fit_and_print_params(x, y, label, color, linestyle):
    # Initial guess for the parameters
    p0 = [1, 0, 1, 10]

    # Fit the curve
    popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, x, y, p0=p0, maxfev=8000)
    a_opt = popt[0]
    b_opt = popt[1]
    mu_opt = popt[2]
    sigma_opt = popt[3]

    print(f"Optimized values for {label}:")
    print("a =", a_opt)
    print("b =", b_opt)
    print("mu =", mu_opt)
    print("sigma =", sigma_opt)

    # Calculate R-squared
    y_fit = func(x, *popt)
    residuals = y - y_fit
    ss_residuals = np.sum(residuals**2)
    ss_total = np.sum((y - np.mean(y))**2)
    r_squared = 1 - (ss_residuals / ss_total)
    print("R-squared:", r_squared)

    plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), label=f"Fitted Curve ({label})", color=color, linestyle=linestyle)

Folder1 = '4_1012_nodes_var_1_K_1e3_Cb_1e-3_D_1e-10'
Folder2 = '4_1012_nodes_var_5_K_1e3_Cb_1e-3_D_1e-10'
Folder3 = '4_1012_nodes_var_10_K_1e3_Cb_1e-3_D_1e-10'
Drive='D'

K=1.0e3
Cb0=0.001
DiffCoeff=1.0e-10

y1 = pd.read_csv(rf'{Drive}:\Users\debanikb\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\{Folder1}\Averaged4_0.5__{K}_{Cb0}_{DiffCoeff}_501files.txt',header=None)
y1 =(1 - np.ravel(y1.to_numpy() / 1012))

y2 = pd.read_csv(rf'{Drive}:\Users\debanikb\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\{Folder2}\Averaged4_0.5__{K}_{Cb0}_{DiffCoeff}_501files.txt',header=None)
y2 =(1 - np.ravel(y2.to_numpy() / 1012))

y3 = pd.read_csv(rf'{Drive}:\Users\debanikb\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\{Folder3}\Averaged4_0.5__{K}_{Cb0}_{DiffCoeff}_501files.txt',header=None)
y3 =(1 - np.ravel(y3.to_numpy() / 1012))

x = pd.read_csv(rf'{Drive}:\Users\debanikb\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\{Folder1}\All_values_0_1000001_10000.txt',header=None)
x = np.ravel(x.to_numpy())

plt.plot(x, y1, 'o',linewidth=0.5,label='Simulation (var 1)')
fit_and_print_params(x, y1, 'var 1', color='red', linestyle='--')

plt.plot(x, y2, 'o', label='Simulation (var 5)')
fit_and_print_params(x, y2, 'var 5', color='blue', linestyle='-.') 

plt.plot(x, y3, 'o', label='Simulation (var 10)')
fit_and_print_params(x, y3, 'var 10', color='black', linestyle=':')

plt.xlabel("Elapsed time (sec)",fontsize=15.0)
plt.ylabel("Invaded fraction",fontsize=15.0)
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.xlim(0, 1e6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your that your data will fit an error function? You could try fitting other sigmoid (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#/media/File:Gjl-t(x).svg) type functions.

Comment: Can you provide data?

Comment: The data departs from a sigmoid because data is a lot sharper at the first bend than at the second. I would expect them to be similar for a sigmoid.